# Minimum Spanning Tree with only 2 equal edges

Tags: algorithm

Assume you have an undirected-weighted graph **G**, with different edges weighs but for only two edges: `w(e1)=w(e2)`

I have to prove that G has at most one minimum spanning tree which includes e1.
Also I have to prove that G has at most one minimum spanning tree which doesnt include e1.

I only need a solution for the first one and will solve the second one alone.

Thanks

Comment: except for these two edges, all the weights on all the edges are different? those are the only two edges with same weight?

Comment: @YossiVainshtein Yes

Comment: You might find a better answer on Computer Science.SE or Mathematics.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving part 1:

Consider the graph you get by removing `e1` from G (and possibly one of it's vertices, if it's now not connected to the rest of the graph), let's call it G'.

In this graph (G') , **all** the edge weights are different.

Now suppose G has more than 1 MST which includes `e1` - they would both be different MSTs for G'.

Now the trick is that there's a theorem that in this kind of graph (all edges are different), the MST is unique. see the proof(s) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352163/show-that-theres-a-minimum-spanning-tree-if-all-edges-have-different-costs).

edit: You can probably just take the proof from the link and edit it slightly for your case.

Comment: you mean removing e2 ? because removing e1 won't help

Comment: Now I get it! NVM my note :P